# ExttJS 6 Class theme applied to all components

Tags: extjs, themes

Using ExtJS6 MVVC.  In my application folder I have a sass folder that will allow me to theme my individual components:

```
Application
+---app
+---overrides
+---resources
+---sass
    +---var
        +---view
            +---shared
                +---AttDataGrid.scss
```

The AttDataGrid.scss is supposed to theme just the grid class that was created in app/view/shared/AttDataGrid.js; however it is applying the theme to all grids in the application.  How do I theme ONLY the class component?

Comment: You can use a css class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grid would need to have certain CSS classes which are exclusively used by that grid class. E.g. you could set

[`componentCls`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-componentCls)`: 'attdatagrid'`

Then you would put your whole SCSS code under that class, so if your SCSS file is now

```
.x-grid-cell {font-weight:bold}
.x-grid-cell-focused {font-decoration:overline}
```

you would make that

```
.attdatagrid {
    .x-grid-cell {font-weight:bold}
    .x-grid-cell-focused {font-decoration:overline}
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am attempting to use the CSSVars.  The documentation is sketchy at best.

Comment: You can also use CSSVars, but you have(!) to use a custom CSS class.

Comment: Where would the SCSS file live?  In the same folder as I have it?

Comment: Yes, you have chosen the correct path. It is included into your SCSS, isn't it? So you may guess that the file is found correctly.

Comment: Alexander, I do appreciate your help.  I have modified the SCSS file to to look like what you have above, placed it in the correct folder and applied the componentCls to the grid panel.  Sencha app refresh but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Please post thr relevant parts of your code so I can sift through it and look for errors.

Comment: Sometimes when you focus so hard on something the obvious slips right past you.  The componentCls needed to be placed on the viewConfig, not the grid panel.  Seems to work now.  Thanks for your help!